# Ionic Inapp Purchase

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I want to add inapp purchase into my ionic app(for ios). I have installed the plugin and npm package using these commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inapppurchase
npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-purchase
```

And in my code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage { 
constructor(
    private plateform: Platform,
    private iap: InAppPurchase
  ) {
    this.plateform.ready().then(() => {
        this.iap.buy(PRODUCT_KEY).then((res) => {
          console.log("Purchase completed!");
        }).catch(err => console.log("Purchase Error!", err))
    });
  }
}
```

This code is return error: `Purchase Error! plugin_not_installed`.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to uninstall plugin and reinstall again. You can also do `ionic cordova prepare ios`. If it doesn't work, delete ios platform `ionic cordova platform rm ios` and reinstall after. You can also delete `plugins` folder et do `ionic cordova prepare ios`

Comment: Please note that the plugin cordova-plugin-inapppurchase is not being maintained. You should probably look into this one instead: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase -- Also, the `Promise` approach it uses has severe drawbacks: it will fail most edge cases when for whatever reason you can't finalize a transaction properly, the platform tries to process it on another device or at a subsequent run. People might pay for a product that you won't be able to deliver.